# Google Form Response Submit and Google Sheet Update

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I have a script I am working on and need some help.

First how my script is supposed to work.

**Script:** A user fills out google form and hits submit. Upon submit my script runs and reads from the google sheet a range of data cells that I manipulate in sheets. The data cells then get formatted into a string and prompted in the Confirmation Message of the form.

Now for the problem.

**Problem:**
When I submit my responses to the form everything from sheets works fine. When I run my code manually the code works fine. When I submit my form responses, the event history shows the trigger and says it completes, but the end result(the confirmation message updating) doesn't take place.

Answer (score 0):

Not Possible.

`FormSubmit` trigger and subsequent  script execution is a asynchronous operation. The Form doesn't wait for the script to complete(and change the confirmation message). You can send a email for confirmation.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the trigger to a timed trigger and now it does mostly what I want.